# can I dynamically change/replace "mycontentblock" with ampscript variable in landing pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

can I dynamically change/replace "mycontentblock" in %%=ContentBlockbyKey("myContentBlock")=%% in with ampscript variable in landing pages - eg : %%=ContentBlockbyKey("@contentname")=%%.its not work for me! any other idea!

Comment: You just need to remove the double quotes around @contentname and as long as the value of that var is the Content Block's key, it will work.

Comment: Thanks, @Gortonington. can I use dynamic content block in landing page too?

Comment: yes - you just set the variable @contentname inside a conditional statement that will fill in the appropriate key depending on your requirements.

Comment: @Gortonington -But, conditional statement only profile attributes or DE attributes, how to set ampscript variable? and I just check in trailblazer community - Dynamic content in landing pages that still in idea section only - success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKsZQAU , did you implemented anywhere.

Comment: you do like this: `SET @var = AttributeValue("yourVar")` [or if not via MicrositeURL() then via a Lookup()] and then `IF @var == "var1" THEN  set @contentname = "content1"  ELSE SET @contentname = "defaultcontent" ENDIF`

Comment: @Gortonington Actually, I created Dynamic content (if interest is sport then show sports product else default product ) in content builder and call that in landindpages. Its simple render both default & conditional  content too. I need to know that how to pass interest value to validate that is sport or not in landing pages using ampscript variable?

Comment: Only option I could think of is if inside the email you create your link using Microsite URL or CloudPages URL functions in AMPscript. I honestly am not sure if that would work, but best guess I can provide as that should pass all the data from email to LP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use the other content functions like [ContentBlockbyId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyid.htm) or [ContentBlockbyName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyname.htm)?

Also I recommend you to decompose your code in first declaring the variable and then calling the content. You can do it in one of course but to start it is easier to debug.

**ContentBlockbyId**

First retrieve the ID of the content box:

[image]

Add this code in your landing page:

```
%%[ 
SET @ContentID = "58512" 
SET @Content = ContentBlockbyID(@ContentID) 
]%% 

%%=TreatAsContent(@Content)=%%
```

OR

```
%%[ 
SET @ContentID = "58512" 
output(ContentBlockbyID(@ContentID)) 
]%%
```

**ContentBlockbyName**

First retrieve the path of the content box:
[image]

Add this code in your landing page:

```
%%[ 
SET @ContentName = "Shared Content\Master Template\Assets\Content Blocks\Big CTA" 
]%% 

%%=ContentBlockByName(@ContentName)=%%
```

If you want this to be dynamic, you will have to modify the @ContentID or @ContentName. Make sure to set a default content in case you dynamic value does not match an actual content.

This should help you get started.

Comment: You explained it like a pro